# TSQL: effect of "USE" directive for specific database on query performance

Tags: performance, sql-server-2008, t-sql, select, sql-server-2008-r2

T-SQL: does a "USE" directive improve query performance?

I am using SQL Server 2008 R2, if that has bearing on the question.

Assume that the entire query takes place within the database (all selects and joins).

Example:

```
USE ourDatabase1

SELECT T1.id, T2.id, T1.Col1, T1.Col2, T2.Col3
FROM [table1] T1
LEFT JOIN [table2] T2 ON (T1.id = T2.id)
WHERE (T1.Col1 IS NOT NULL)
ORDER BY T1.Col1, T1.Col2
```

For purposes of this question, one can consider read-only queries, but if people are knowledgeable about other queries, that may be included also.

NOTE:  I saw the similar question about FORTRAN, but this would not be directly relevant here.

(See [Effect of `USE` on performance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21255790/effect-of-use-on-performance))

Comment: It doesn't affect query performance, but it improves my typing performance.

Comment: @EricBrandt LOL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is just syntax

It assigns the default database so you don't have to use

```
FROM [ourDatabase1].[dbo].[table1]
```

Answer (score 1):

No, all it does is change the database in which the following code is executed.